# How one can translate a statement to an equation of the form $g=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logic

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a non constant real function.
$$\lim_{s→1}f(s)=c⇔∀ε>0,∃δ>0,∀s:|s-1|<δ⇒|f(s)-c|<ε$$
$$\lim_{s→1}f(s)=c⇔∀ε>0,∃δ>0,∀s:-δ+1<s<1+δ⇒-ε+f(s)<c<ε+f(s)\tag{$*$}$$

If we know that $$a<b⇔∃d>0:a+d=b$$

How one can translate the second statement in the equivalence $(*)$ to an equation of the form $g=0$, i.e., 
$$\lim_{s→1}f(s)=c⇔g=0$$

Here the **variables** of $g$ are to be definied from the second statement in the equivalence $(*)$.

My **solution**:

$∀ε>0,∃δ>0,∀s,∃δ₁>0,∃δ₂>0,∃δ₃>0,∃δ₄>0:-δ+1+δ₁=s$ and $s+δ₂=1+δ$ and $-ε+f(s)+δ₃=c$ and $c+δ₄=ε+f(s)$

Define $$g(ε,δ,s,δ₁,δ₂,δ₃,δ₄)=(-δ+1+δ₁-s)²+(s+δ₂-(1+δ))²+(-ε+f(s)+δ₃-c)²+(c+δ₄-ε-f(s))²$$

Then we get:

$$\lim_{s→1}f(s)=c⇔∀ε>0,∃δ>0,∀s,∃δ₁>0,∃δ₂>0,∃δ₃>0,∃δ₄>0: g(ε,δ,s,δ₁,δ₂,δ₃,δ₄)=0$$

However, I have some doubts about translating the implication in $(*)$.

Comment: May I ask why are you complicating the notion of a limit so much?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: I need this in a dynamical systems problem: The notion of a limit is equivalent to an equation.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Seems allright to me.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: This is to use in the notion of limit sets associated with discrete mappings.